# USB pen drive randomly disconnects

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, connection

When I connect a USB pen drive in my computer it randomly disconnects. I already unchecked the power manager option in the device manager.
I have the same problem in XP & Windows 7. I tried with Ubuntu on the same machine without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had such an issue: too long USB cable was the case.
Later it came out again, and I've changed my pen-drive: it was a hardware issue :)

Check if your USB port is in good state, and check whether its connectors to the motherboard are okay and sit tight.

Comment: On a related note, I have had ports I use frequently fail.

Comment: Sure, motherboards can also be imperfect :)

Comment: Zoredache, frequent use can certainly [wear down a connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gebrochene_loetstellen.jpg)

o_O Tync, Two words: [cold joints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldering#Soldering_defects).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with a combination of usb card reader and old CF cards.

Basically issue was the card didn't allow simultaneous read writes. But somehow the system did try to do it - which caused it to immediatly eject.

After turning off thumbnails, indexing and also taking care I did not do any browsing on the card during read/writes I could use it "normally".

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.

> Open power options --> change plan settings --> change advanced power
>   settings Check for usb settings --> usb selective suspend mode

Set it to disabled